# Entity Framework Code First Common Database Audit Fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, entity-framework-5

I'm new to Entity Framework, in the past I've used Enterprise Library or ADO.NET directly to map models to database tables. One pattern that I've used is to put my common audit fields that appear in every table in a Base Class and then inherit that Base Class for every object.

I take two steps to protect two of the fields (Created, CreatedBy):

1. Have a parameterless constructor private on the Base Enitity and create a second one that requires Created and CreatedBy are passed on creation.
2. Make the setters Private so that the values cannot be changed after the object is created.

**Base Class:**

```
using System;

namespace App.Model
{
    [Serializable()]
    public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public bool IsActive { get; private set; }
        public DateTimeOffset Created { get; private set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; private set; }
        public DateTimeOffset LastUpdated { get; protected set; }
        public string LastUpdatedBy { get; protected set; }

        private BaseEntity() { }

        protected BaseEntity(DateTimeOffset created, string createdBy)
        {
            IsActive = true;
            Created = created;
            CreatedBy = createdBy;
            LastUpdated = created;
            LastUpdatedBy = createdBy;
        }
    }
}
```

**Inherited Class:**

```
using System;

namespace App.Model
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class Person : BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public Person(DateTimeOffset created, string createdBy) : 
            base(created, createdBy) {  }
    }
}
```

I've run into issues with both. EF requires a parameterless constructor to create objects. EF will not create the database columns that have a private setter.

My question is if there is a better approach to accomplish my goals with EF:

1. Require that the values for Created and CreatedBy are populated at instantiation.
2. The values of Created and CreatedBy cannot be changed.

Comment: There's another option: override `SaveChanges` in your context and do all audit-related actions there (setting creation date on new entities, setting modification date on updated entities etc). It will all be done just before save.

Comment: [I had the same problem and found this helpful.](http://jmdority.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/using-entity-framework-4-1-dbcontext-change-tracking-for-audit-logging/)

Comment: I would implement an interface `IAuditiable` instead, that way you can still have entities that shouldnt be audited, and the ones that should you can implement logic specific to that interface in your SaveChanges() call like suggested in one of the answers below, if thats what you want.

Comment: @FRoZeN, you cannot have non-public setters from on an Interface so that wouldn't meet my second goal.

Answer (score 5):

You could instantiate a context with a constructor that accepts a string `createdBy`. Then in an override of `SaveChanges()`:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach( var entity in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added)
                                        .Select (e => e.Entity)
                                        .OfType<BaseEntity>())
    {
        entity.SetAuditValues(DateTimeOffset.Now, this.CreatedBy);
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

With `SetAuditValues()` as

```
internal void SetAuditValues(DateTimeOffset created, string createdBy)
{
    if (this.Created == DateTimeOffset.MinValue) this.Created = created;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CreatedBy)) this.CreatedBy = createdBy;
}
```

After the entities have been materialized from the database the values won't be overwritten when someone calls `SetAuditValues`.

Comment: This looks close, but I still have the issue with the columns not being created because the setters are private. I could make them protected, but then someone could just call Person.Created = new-value. It wouldn't be saved to the database because of SetAuditValues, but it would be an invalid state while in memory prior to saving.

Comment: You should be able to add the properties to the model by fluent mapping, isn't it?

Comment: Yes and No -- you have to use an Alias read-only field to get around the Private Setter issue with fluent mapping. The solution is a bit of a hack.

Comment: I have my models in a separate project from the Data project (which contains the Context). This means I have to make the SetAuditValues function Public, so the audit fields could be updated by any process.

Comment: Although this is an interesting approach, the issue I see is that the values for Created and CreatedBy properties can be set prior to the SetAuditValues() being called because they cannot be set to private. Then the parameters passed to SetAuditValues() would ignored because the entities property are already set.

Comment: Yes, I see the problems and possible loopholes creating their own problems. The root of the issues is in fact that separation of concerns is not obeyed. Your entities should not worry about these cross-cutting concerns. That's why I always try to avoid base types for any other reason than "real" polymorphism because it's always done to introduce something that's not domain specific. Maybe an aspect oriented programming tool like PostSharp could help you out. For the rest this is just a lot of rambling while waiting for a brain wave.

Comment: The primary use of my Base Class is to follow DRY, since the audit properties would appear in each class and related table it makes sense to declare once in the object model. Which layer has should have the concern about the valid state of an object? When we save to database it makes sense that the Data layer validates, but since a program could have an object in memory before saving to the database, shouldn't we make sure it is valid when properties are set? Or does this go against the POCO concept?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to control access rights directly on your entities/data layer instead your should do this in your application layer.  This way you have a finer level of control over what users can do what.

Also rather than have the audit fields repeated on every table you might want to store your Audit records in another table.  This is easy to do with code first:

```
public class AuitRecord
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

You would then link the base class with the audit record to it:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public AuditRecord Audit { get; set; }
}
```

And finally your actually entities

```
public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

You can no access the audit data by going:

```
Person.Audit.IsActive
```

Comment: Interesting but it doesn't meet the goal of requiring that Created and CreatedBy are populated when the object is created. Also, having a separate Audit table means you would need a key (not shown in the AuditClass) that could reference any of the other entity keys. This would not be 3rd normal form. The other issue with a common audit table I've run into is a performance issue because it becomes a bottle neck for performance.

Comment: @Josh:  You can actually remain in 3NF by adding a key to the AuditRecord class and having all of your other entities contain a `List<AuditRecord>` (which would create one-to-many relationship with all of your audited entities and the audit table).  This will only be a bottleneck for inserts and updates (which should be optimized to be as quick as possible anyway), so it may not be an issue depending on your requirements/implementation.